# Rcpp + inline - creating and calling additional functions

Tags: r, rcpp

I would like to know if there is a way to create `Rcpp` functions using the  `inline` packages within the main function. This is an example of what I want to do:

```
library(inline)
library(Rcpp)
a = 1:10
cpp.fun = cxxfunction(signature(data1="numeric"), 
                      plugin="Rcpp",
                      body="
int fun1( int a1)
{int b1 = a1;
 b1 = b1*b1;
 return(b1);
}

NumericVector fun_data  = data1;
int n = data1.size();
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
fun_data[i] = fun1(fun_data[i]);
}
return(fun_data);
                           ")
```

which should result in:

```
> cpp.fun(a)
[1]  1  4  9  16  25  36  49  64  81  100
```

however I know that the compiler will not accept the creation of your own function within the main method. How will I go about creating and calling another `Rcpp` function with `inline` without having to pass it through to R?

Answer (score 15):

`body` is for the body of the function, you want to look at the `includes` argument of `cxxfunction`:

```
library(inline)
library(Rcpp)
a = 1:10
cpp.fun = cxxfunction(signature(data1="numeric"), 
                      plugin="Rcpp",
                      body='

IntegerVector fun_data  = data1;
int n = fun_data.size();
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    fun_data[i] = fun1(fun_data[i]);
}
return(fun_data);
', includes = '

int fun1( int a1){
    int b1 = a1;
    b1 = b1*b1;
    return(b1);
}

' )    
cpp.fun( a )
```

`?cxxfunction` has detailed documentation about its `includes` argument.

But note that this version will make in place modifications in your input vector, which is probably not what you want. Another version that also takes advantage of `Rcpp` version of `sapply`:

```
library(inline)
library(Rcpp)
a = 1:10
cpp.fun = cxxfunction(signature(data1="numeric"), 
                      plugin="Rcpp",
                      body='

IntegerVector fun_data  = data1; 
IntegerVector out = sapply( fun_data, fun1 ) ;
return(out);
', includes = '

int fun1( int a1){
    int b1 = a1;
    b1 = b1*b1;
    return(b1);
}

' )    
cpp.fun( a )
a
```

Finally, you definitely should have a look at `sourceCpp`. With it you would write your code in a `.cpp` file, containing:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp ;

int fun1( int a1){
    int b1 = a1;
    b1 = b1*b1;
    return(b1);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector fun(IntegerVector fun_data){ 
    IntegerVector out = sapply( fun_data, fun1 ) ;
    return(out);
}
```

And then, you can just `sourceCpp` your file and invoke the function :

```
sourceCpp( "file.cpp" )
fun( 1:10 )
#  [1]   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81 100
```